# Testcontainers on Ubuntu can't find docker endpoint

Tags: ubuntu, xunit.net, testcontainers

I'm trying to get Testcontainers working to fire up a simple container based on one of the examples from the Testcontainers.org website.  Docker is working fine locally (tested using docker run hello-world).  When I try to run my unit test (xUnit .net) it throws an error:

```
System.ArgumentException: Cannot detect the Docker endpoint. Use either the environment variables or the ~/.testcontainers.properties file to customiz...

System.ArgumentException
Cannot detect the Docker endpoint. Use either the environment variables or the ~/.testcontainers.properties file to customize your configuration:
https://dotnet.testcontainers.org/custom_configuration/ (Parameter 'DockerEndpointAuthConfig')
```

I've tried setting environment variables:

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("DOCKER_HOST", "tcp://0.0.0.0:2376");
```

*or*

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("DOCKER_HOST", "http://0.0.0.0:2376");
```

*or*

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("DOCKER_HOST", "unix:///var/run/docker.sock");
```

Terminal output showing dockerd is running:

```
NFO[2023-05-12T18:05:37.014550250+02:00] Starting up                                  
WARN[2023-05-12T18:05:37.014869491+02:00] Binding to IP address without --tlsverify is insecure and gives root access on this machine to everyone who has access to your network.  host="tcp://0.0.0.0:2376"
WARN[2023-05-12T18:05:37.014878812+02:00] Binding to an IP address, even on localhost, can also give access to scripts run in a browser. Be safe out there!  host="tcp://0.0.0.0:2376"
WARN[2023-05-12T18:05:38.015027178+02:00] Binding to an IP address without --tlsverify is deprecated. Startup is intentionally being slowed down to show this message  host="tcp://0.0.0.0:2376"
WARN[2023-05-12T18:05:38.015083554+02:00] Please consider generating tls certificates with client validation to prevent exposing unauthenticated root access to your network  host="tcp://0.0.0.0:2376"
WARN[2023-05-12T18:05:38.015124538+02:00] You can override this by explicitly specifying '--tls=false' or '--tlsverify=false'  host="tcp://0.0.0.0:2376"
WARN[2023-05-12T18:05:38.015154045+02:00] Support for listening on TCP without authentication or explicit intent to run without authentication will be removed in the next release  host="tcp://0.0.0.0:2376"
INFO[2023-05-12T18:05:53.022198864+02:00] detected 127.0.0.53 nameserver, assuming systemd-resolved, so using resolv.conf: /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf 
INFO[2023-05-12T18:05:53.057360176+02:00] [graphdriver] using prior storage driver: overlay2 
INFO[2023-05-12T18:05:53.147997987+02:00] Loading containers: start.                   
INFO[2023-05-12T18:05:53.746994856+02:00] Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP address {removed}. Daemon option --bip can be used to set a preferred IP address 
INFO[2023-05-12T18:05:53.831842924+02:00] Loading containers: done.                    
WARN[2023-05-12T18:05:53.845836526+02:00] WARNING: API is accessible on http://0.0.0.0:2376 without encryption.
     Access to the remote API is equivalent to root access on the host. Refer
     to the 'Docker daemon attack surface' section in the documentation for
     more information: https://docs.docker.com/go/attack-surface/ 
INFO[2023-05-12T18:05:53.845872844+02:00] Docker daemon                                 commit=9dbdbd4 graphdriver=overlay2 version=23.0.6
INFO[2023-05-12T18:05:53.846109976+02:00] Daemon has completed initialization          
INFO[2023-05-12T18:05:53.869117852+02:00] API listen on [::]:2376                      
INFO[2023-05-12T18:05:53.871846788+02:00] API listen on /var/run/docker.sock
```

**Running**:

Ubuntu 22.04

Testcontainers 3.1.0